# ReactJs custom submit button component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a custom submit button component that will handle the button disabling-enabling by itself. So far I got this:

Button component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Promise = require('promise');

let isDisabled = false;

const buttonClickHandler = onClick => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('inside promise');
    isDisabled = true;
    onClick();
    return resolve(true);
  });
};

export const SubmitButton = ({
  type,
  className,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle = {},
  children
}) => {
  return (
    <button
      type={type || 'submit'}
      className={className}
      onClick={() =>
        buttonClickHandler(onClick).then(() => {
          console.log('after promise');
          isDisabled = false;
        })
      }
      style={buttonStyle}
      disabled={isDisabled}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default SubmitButton;
```

I'm calling this like this:

```
<SubmitButton type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.submitForm}>
Submit
</SubmitButton>
```

The form submit function is:

```
public submitForm = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('waiting done');
  }, 5000);
};
```

So the expected output is

`inside promise`
----wait 5000 ms----
`waiting done`
`after promise`

But I'm seeing
`inside promise`
`after promise`
----wait 5000 ms----
`waiting done`

So what did I do wrong? Also the button is not being disabled.

Comment: What are you working in that you can't use native/vanilla javascript Promise?

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: Move the isDisabled to state. Your component does not rerenders when a variable from outside changes.

Comment: Button isn't disabled because `isDisabled` isn't a state or prop value, and the `buttonClickHandler` immediately resolves. All it does is resolve immediately and then invoke the external `onClick` callback that sets up the timeout. Are you trying to resolve the initial promise in 5 seconds before calling the callback?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm using the setTimeOut just to mimic a db call. the button will keep disabled until the call ends. but yes i think i must use state to handle disabling/enabling.

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections to be made:

- isDisabled needs to be a state and not a global variable
- move the `buttonClickHandler` function with in the `SubmitButton` component
- The `onClick()` inside the `SubmmitButton` component needs to return a promise

working copy of your [code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-maps-bpu8s?file=/src/SubmitButton.js)

```js
export const SubmitButton = ({
  type,
  className,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle = {},
  children
}) => {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);
  const buttonClickHandler = onClick => {
    // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("inside promise");
    setIsDisabled(true);
    return onClick();
    // });
  };
  return (
    <button
      type={type || "submit"}
      className={className}
      onClick={() =>
        buttonClickHandler(onClick).then(() => {
          console.log("after promise");
          setIsDisabled(false);
        })
      }
      style={buttonStyle}
      disabled={isDisabled}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default SubmitButton;
```

**Usage**

```js
const submitForm = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("waiting done");
        res(true);
      }, 5000);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Given some database call that resolves in some time within 10 seconds

```
const dbCall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("inside promise, making DB call");
    setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
  });
};
```

And some `submitForm` handler

```
const submitForm = () => {
  console.log("submitForm called");
  return dbCall();
};
```

Add state to the button, and an internal onClick handler to manage state

```
const SubmitButton = ({
  type,
  className,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle = {},
  children
}) => {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState();

  const clickHandler =  async () => {
    setIsDisabled(true);
    await onClick();
    console.log("after promise");
    setIsDisabled(false);
  }

  return (
    <button
      type={type || "submit"}
      className={className}
      onClick={clickHandler}
      style={buttonStyle}
      disabled={isDisabled}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Demo

[image: Edit adoring-https-4psuu]

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer to your approach lies in the fact that **Javascript** is asynchronous in nature.

To ensure, execution happens synchronously, we use `Promises` like you already did in your current code.

You just need few tweaks here.

Firstly you need to make your function `submitForm` return a `Promise`

```
let submitForm = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('waiting done');
    }, 5000);
  })
};
```

And then you need to make sure that `submitForm` finishes executing before resolving 
`buttonClickHandler` function

```
const buttonClickHandler = (onClick) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('inside promise');
    isDisabled = true;
    onClick().then((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
      return resolve(true);
    });
  });
};
```

P.S: Code can always be refactored

- Avoid using reserved keywords like `onClick` as user defined functions
  or variables names it's gonna give you errors.
- I recommend you to use `state` for managing `loading`.